# How to properly call React component again?

Tags: reactjs

How to properly call React component again?

There is a Parent component and Child component.
There is code that Child component doesn't render until `showResults` is true `{showResults && <Child arr={animals} />}`. It renders only when I click on `Load` button.

```
    
const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([]);
const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(false);
        
function Load() {
  setShowResults(true);
}

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={async () => Load()}> Load Info </button>
    {showResults && <Child arr={animals} />}
  </>)
```

I can check that `animals` prop is updating if I change them. But Child component has their own functions inside, and renders only once and doesn't change,
So how do I properly call Child component again when I click on button?

Comment: Do you mean you want to reload the Child on the second click on the button? If so, right now the child component doesn't have any reason to rerender, a rerender only occurs on a state change relevant to the component (meaning in this case on `animals` state change).
Reloading `animals` is really dependent on your business logic, based on the information given it shoud go in the Load() function.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're doing with `animals` or what happens/doesn't happen in `<Child />`, but I have a strong feeling that you're addressing the wrong problem. That this is just a patch for a different Problem. Like, If `<Child />` doesn't do what it's supposed to do, why don't you fix that instead?

Comment: @GonnenDaube Yes,I mean reload. Right now it loads only on first call of component

Comment: @Thomas `<Child />` does what it supposed to do, but only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Thomas `<Child />` does what it supposed to do, but only once.

Like a car that only drives once to a destination and then stops working.

Nevermind.

The simplest way to "reset" this component then is to destroy it and create a new one ... by changing the `key`

```
const childKey = "" + React.useMemo(Math.random, [animals]);

// ...

{showResults && <Child key={childKey} arr={animals} />}
```

this creates a new random `childKey`, every time `animals` changes. So every time `animals` changes and `showResults` is truthy, the old `<Child />` will be destroyed and a new one will be mounted.

Comment: Ty for your help, this solution worked. Also I got it that it's not proper way (?) and I need to change <Card /> component inside.

Answer (score 1):

React by default re-renders child components when parent components are re-rendered i.e a  **state changes** in parent component.

I have illustrated it better in this codesandbox.
You can check this out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-cori-ry799n?file=/src/App.js

**Inshort:**  Changing a state in parent component should re-render child component.

Answer (score 1):

You think the child component hasn't been rendered, but here what's happening is that even the parent hasn't, because it only does when one or more of its `useState` hooks are updated
The first time the button is clicked `showResults` passes from `false` to `true` this triggers a render
The second time it passes from `true` to `true` so the component do not rerender 
one simple solution is to update your function :

```js
function Load() {
  setShowResults(!showResults);
}
```

This will trigger a render on every click.

get rid of `showResults &&` if you want to show `child` updates on every click or leave it if you want `child` to be shown only when `showResults` is `true` so the button will play the role of SHOW and HIDE

Comment: Thank you, but it's not updates on every click. I use inside <Child/> async function, and everything works, but only once.